are events second card Ace and second card Spade independent?
Two cards are drawn at random from a deck of 52 cards. 
Are the events “the second card is an ace” and “the second card is a spade” independent?
I have solved similar tasks when there are options with first and second card, but here the question is about the same second card which confused me. So let A be "second card is Ace" and B be "second card is Spade". $P(A)=4/51$, because the first card is already taken from the deck. $P(B)=13/51$ So the problem is that these probabilities are as if i don't care about the first drawn card. What if it was an ace or a spade or an ace and a spade? Does it mean i have to consider four cases, which seems not logical?
Or am I suppposed to not consider the first take of card? Then
P(A) = 4/52 = 1/13 (there are 4 aces in a deck of 52 cards)
P(B) = 13/52 = 1/4 (there are 13 spades in a deck of 52 cards)
P(B|A) = 1/4 (there is 1 ace of spades among the 4 aces)
Since P(B|A) = 1/4 = P(B), A and B are independent.

The first card is irrelevant...each card in the deck is equally likely to appear as the second selection.  And your calculation is correct, the events are independent.

Should say:  if you wished, you could, of course, condition on the outcome of the first selection.  Just to confirm the, much better, calculation you already did.  For two selections, the full calculation isn't terrible...though you wouldn't want to do it this way for, say, the $26^{th}$ selection.

You think the second card is more likely to be a spade than the first card? Is it also more likely to be a heart, a diamond, or a club?

@lulu thank you I got it!

Note that in the $~52~$ card deck, exactly $~(1/4)$-th of the cards are spades.  Further, if you confine the selection to the $~4~$ aces, again, exactly $~(1/4)$-th of the cards are spades.  So, because the ratio of $~(1/4)$-th is unchanged, narrowing the selection to the $~4~$ aces does not affect (i.e. is independent of) the chance of a spade.
